# Angular UI Grid callbacks not received

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to get a callback from the Angular UI grid (after data is loaded/rendered) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm following [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Grid-Events) which says I should listen the scope using `$scope.$on()` and I tried [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options) which implies I can provide a `dataUpdated()` and `init()` delegate through the options.

**In both cases I don't see anything in my console...** The grid renders fine and I can also see a console entry stating: 'grid refresh'.

I'm loading the grid with the following options:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventRows', function (event) {
    console.log('rendering');
});

$scope.$on('ngGridEventRows', function (event) {
    console.log('rendering');
});

        $scope.options = {
            enableSorting: true,
            //data: myData,
            dataUpdated: function() {
                console.log('dataUpdated');
            },
            init: function () {
                console.log('init');
            }
        };

    $scope.grids = [$scope.options];
```

The options are passed to the grid as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-repeat="grid in grids">
    <div ui-grid="grid" ui-grid-exporter></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you pass that `$scope.options` object to your grid?

Comment: @Starscream1984: I'm actually putting it in an array first, please check my updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those events are related to ng-grid (probably version 2.x) while you are using ui-grid (which is a rename of ng-grid version 3.0).

I'd suggest you to give a look at the updated website ui-grid.info where you can find docs and tutorials about the current version.

Regarding your peculiar need sadly it seems there is no documented event you can use, but looking through the code I found the following:

```
$scope.grid.api.core.on.rowsRendered( $scope, function() );
```

You should put this in your `gridOptions.onRegisterApi(...)` and the function will be called upon rendering is complete (or so it seems looking at the [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/e89598a588791a6fc18a040c00a805dc1b6c5d25/src/js/core/factories/Grid.js#L1372)).

I'd suggest you to play a bit with it and see what it can do.